# Hello samza not able to run properly in windows 7

Tags: apache-samza

I did everything as shown in http://samza.apache.org/startup/hello-samza/0.13/
Basically, clone the repo and type "bin/grid bootstrap". However in the end I got an error message saying zookeeper not able to start as shown below, does anyone know how can I fix this problem and what else I should do to make it work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute script `bin/grid bootstrap`, but in line 191 there is an error. In that line script tries to `nc -w 1 localhost $PORT`.

In other words, trying to execute `netcat` command from your own terminal.

Check with the command `zkServer.cmd`, that zookeeper server is up and running **or** check that you can successful execute a netcat command.